# How do I access a multistep form using the URL?

Tags: 8, forms

I followed the [Examples for developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) to create a 5-step form. I want to access the third and fourth step using the URL, so I tried test/page_num/2, but it seems it doesn't work.

Is there any way to access the form for a specific step?

Comment: Please elaborate the question with the code snippet so that it will be easy for us to understand

Comment: You must have defined the routes for this?